# Lucene.net index in php

Tags: .net, lucene.net, zend-search-lucene

Is it possible to query an Index made with Lucene.NET through a PHP front-end? I've heard about Zend_Search_Lucene but not sure whether it can do the job or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently supported Lucene index format versions in Zend_Search_Lucene are 1.4 - 2.3.